# how can I make this c# method generic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, asp.net-web-api

I have the class below which is used to validate if a user submits an API request with an invalid property.  I'd like to make this class generic.  For example, I'd like to use this class generically with any type of request object.  For example, UserSearchRequest, GroupSearchRequest, XSearchRequest, etc.

I had originally explicitly set the type for DeserializeObject to UserSearchRequest which worked as expected but now I'm trying to genericize this implementation.  I tried providing a T to the BindModel() signature but the current signature is required in order to support the IModelBinder interface.

My current thought is to have a class constructor which takes a Type parameter, which then sets that to a member variable, which then gets referenced within the BindModel method.  But I'm not able to get this working.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
using Models.Requests;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyCorp.Api
{
    public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        Type _bindModelType;

        public CustomModelBinder(Type bindModelType)
        {
            _bindModelType = bindModelType;
        }

        public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
            };

            try
            {
                bindingContext.Model =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<_bindModelType.GetType()>(
                    actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result,
                    settings);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var split = ex.Message.Split("'".ToCharArray());
                var message = "{0}.{1} is not a valid property";
                var formattedMessage = string.Format(message, split[3], split[1]);
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("extraProperty", formattedMessage);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to make a generic method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx - This way you can call the generic method with a type known at runtime (don't do `_bindModelType.GetType()`, just use `_bindModelType`)

Comment: @DennisKuypers I tried just using _bindModelType but that returns compile error: "The type or namespace name '_bindModelType' could not be found."  So I tried typeof(_bindModelType) and _bindModelType.GetType() but neither of these approaches worked

Comment: Cast to object?

Comment: you can use reflection to get the methodinfo of `DeserializeObject<T>` and then use `MakeGenericMethod` to create the method with your type param using `_bindModelType` - I'll add an answer in a minute

Comment: The specific validation logic will be different for each class, so I see very little room to make anything generic. You could make a abstract class or Interface "VerifiableRequest". Let all those classes inherit/implement it. And then just call the function. If you wanted to add genericness, you could make a function that only takes a type that inherits/implements "verifableRequest". But at that point you might as well just call the function directly.

Comment: I just saw that you don't need generics because you can just pass the type to the non generic method... `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, _bindModelType, settings)`

Comment: @DennisKuypers your last comment is correct.  thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Authored on mobile, might not compile but should point you in the correct direction.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
using Models.Requests;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyCorp.Api
{
    public class CustomModelBinder<T> : IModelBinder
    {
        public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
            };

            try
            {
                bindingContext.Model =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
                    actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result,
                    settings);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var split = ex.Message.Split("'".ToCharArray());
                var message = "{0}.{1} is not a valid property";
                var formattedMessage = string.Format(message, split[3], split[1]);
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("extraProperty", formattedMessage);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```